# is /etc/network/interfaces.d/ redundant with this

Tags: networking, linux

I use a Raspberry Pi, and have the following set in `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# static IP configuration:
denyinterfaces wlan0

interface eth0
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1

interface usb0
static ip_address=10.0.0.2/24
static routers=10.0.0.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
```

Would this make the usb0-cfg, wlan0-cfg, eth0-cfg and lo-cfg files I have in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` redundant?

```
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp

auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

allow-hotplug usb0
iface usb0 inet static
  address 10.0.0.2
  netmask 255.255.255.0
  network 10.0.0.0
  broadcast 10.0.0.255
  gateway 10.0.0.1
  metric 203

allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet static
```

The wlan0 is put down and a monitor mode created in a python script, hence the denyinterfaces wlan0.

Before I just blind remove these files and break my Pi, I thought I'd ask here.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure about this, but I have a *vague recollection* that you should not touch anything in `/etc/network` when using `dhcpcd`.

Comment: As in delete everything there when using dhcpcd, or leave it be?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I set up networking/WiFi/static IP address on Raspbian/Raspberry Pi OS?](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/37920/how-do-i-set-up-networking-wifi-static-ip-address-on-raspbian-raspberry-pi-os)

Comment: No, you need not delete it; IIRC `dhcpcd` writes those `/etc/network` files.

Comment: @Seamus I can assure you `dhcpcd` NEVER writes anything to `/etc/network`.

Comment: @Milliways: thank you so much for your *assurance*. lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed all configuration files in `/etc/network/interfaces.d/` and added the following to `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`:

```
# static IP configuration:
denyinterfaces wlan0

interface eth0
static domain_name_servers=8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
metric=202

interface usb0
static ip_address=10.0.0.2/24
static routers=10.0.0.1
static domain_name_servers=10.0.0.1 8.8.8.8 1.1.1.1
metric=203

interface bnep0
metric=204

interface lo
```

I also edited `/boot/cmdline.txt` with the following line at EOF:

`systemd.restore_state=0 rfkill.default_state=1`

This will automatically set `rfkill unblock all` at boot, each boot.